# More efficient Pandas code

Tags: pandas

I am trying to learn Python and Pandas and coming from VBA I am still caught in the habit of looping through every single cell, but I am looking for ways to operate on entire rows at a time.

Below is my part of my code. I have about 3000 stocks in the columns and about 40 or so data points in the rows saved in a dataframe called df.

I do the same kind of loop as showed to test for multiple criterias based on row values for the stocks in each column. As you see my code uses .ix to loop through the 'cells' in the dataframe.
But I have looked for ways to operate on the entire rows at a time, but have failed every attempt.

This take about 7 minutes for the 3000 stocks (but only about 1 minut or so for 2000 stocks??). But this must be able to run much faster?

```
def piotrosky():

df_temp = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=range(10), columns=df.columns)

#bruger dictionary til rename input så man ikke skal gøre det for hver række
dic={0:'positiveNetIncome',1:'positiveOperatingCF',2:'increasingROA', 3:'QualityOfEarnings',4:'longTermDebtToAssets',
     5:'currentRatio', 6:'sharesOutVsSharesLast',7:'increasingGrossM',8:'IncreasingAssetTurnOver', 9:'total'  }

df_temp.rename(dic, inplace = True)

r=1
#df is a vector with stocks in the columns and datapoints in the rows
#so I always need to loop across the columns
for i in range(df.shape[1]-1):
    #positive net income
    if df.ix[2,r]>0:
        df_temp.ix[0,r]=1
    else:
        df_temp.ix[0,r]=0
    #positiveOpeCF              
    if df.ix[3,r]>0:
        df_temp.ix[1,r]=1
    else:
        df_temp.ix[1,r]=0

     #Continue with several simular loops
     #total
    df_temp.ix[9,r]=df_temp.ix[0,r]+df_temp.ix[1,r]+df_temp.ix[2,r]+df_temp.ix[3,r]+ \
              df_temp.ix[4,r]+df_temp.ix[5,r]+df_temp.ix[6,r]+df_temp.ix[7,r]+df_temp.ix[8,r]

    r=r+1
```

Comment: Nicolaj - `rename(columns=)` takes a dictionary as an argument, so instead of multiple renames, just use `{1:'positiveNetIncome', 2:'positiveOperatingCF', 3:...}`

Comment: That said, you're not going to get many responses the way your question is formed. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion pshep123, I will try to update accordingly

Comment: In my experience, taking the time to create an MCVE often helps me solve the problem myself as I distill the question to the core problem(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

All of the below is done on a dataframe that is the transpose of the one you describe in your post. `df.T` should produce properly formatted input.

**Method:**

For conditionals on pandas dataframes, you can use the `numpy` function `np.where`:

```
criteria = {}
# np.where(condition, value_if_true, value_if_false)
criteria['positive_net_income'] = np.where(df[2] > 0, 1, 0)
```

After you get these numpy arrays, you can construct a dataframe from them,

```
pd.DataFrame(criteria)
```

and sum across it

```
pd.DataFrame(criteria).sum(axis=1)
```

to get a `Series` you can add as a column to your initial DataFrame

```
def piotrosky(df):
    criteria = {}
    criteria['positive_net_income'] = np.where(df[2] > 0, 1, 0)
    criteria['positive_operating_cf'] = np.where(df[3] > 0, 1, 0)
    ...
    return pd.DataFrame(criteria).sum(axis=1)

df['piotrosky_score'] = piotrosky(df)
```

Comment: Perfect! It was something like that I was looking for, your help is very much appreciated

Comment: @NicolajJeppesen - if this answer is what you're looking for, please accept it by clicking the checkmark.